# Solving SQL Query Decision making sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem

I need to select all my contoNames from Conto which was active between FromDate And Todate 
And If i dont get a match in that join i need either to set a NULL or do something else

But i have read that when using AND in your join expression it reads the And statement before it does the join and 
it works like and Where statement filtering data away.

So i dont get a NULL 
In this example 
-- This statement gives 0 rows there is no contractId in that time span

```
SELECT S.Name, C.ContoName, C.fromDate, C.Todate 
From Sales 
    Left outer Sales S on S.ContractId = C.ContractId AND '2014-12-31' BETWEEN c.fromDate AND C.Todate
```

This what i want to achive either to get a NULL value in my left join or do somekind of decision flow 
if no contractId in Timespan then 
Only join on contractId

```
SELECT S.Name, C.ContoName, C.fromDate, C.Todate 
From Sales 
INNER JOIN Sales S on S.ContractId = C.ContractId AND ( '2014-12-31'BETWEEN c.fromDate AND C.Todate OR Sales.ContractId = Conto.ContractId )
```

Not Realistic the AND operator works like a where statement and filtering data before it does the JOIN

```
SELECT S.Name, coalesce(C.ContoName,C1.ContoName)contoName,C.fromDate,C.Todate 
        From Sales S
            LEFT JOIN Conto C on S.ContractId = C.ContractId 
        AND  '2014-12-31' >BETWEEN c.fromDate AND C.Todate )
          LEFT JOIN Conto C1 on S.ContractId = C1.contractId
```

Does anyone have and good idea to solve this in a nice way using tsql or standard sql

Comment: You want to see all your Contacts, even if they are not active in a period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if no contractId in Timespan then Only join on contractId

I am reading this to mean "If there are contractIDs in the Timespan, then only show those.   If there are none in the timespan, then show the ones that aren't in the timespan."

If I'm reading that wrong, then you need to clarify your question.

If I'm right, then you handle this with either a CASE or, as I will show, with an (AND) OR (AND) structure:

```
SELECT S.Name, C.ContoName,C.fromDate,C.Todate 
From Sales S
LEFT JOIN Conto C 
  ON (
    S.ContractId = C.ContractId 
    AND  '2014-12-31' BETWEEN c.fromDate AND C.Todate 
  ) OR (
    S.ContractId = C.ContractId 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM Conto c1
      WHERE S.ContractId = c1.ContractId 
      AND  '2014-12-31' BETWEEN c1.fromDate AND c1.Todate 
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late response, that did the trick for me. Should i do something to close the question properly. Im not used to use stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, please click the checkmark symbol near the top of this answer, and that will close the question.